# GraphQL Subscriptions vs socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io, graphql-subscriptions, ws

I'm trying to make real-time application based on websocket and got two options. One is `socket.io` and the other is `GraphQL Subscriptions`. But it was hard to find comparison of those.

What can be standard to choose one of them and is there any performance difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Socket.IO** is a library that enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between the browser and the server. [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4)

**GraphQL Subscriptions** on another hand is a concept that allows clients to listen to real-time messages from the server.

So basically, **GraphQL Subscriptions** is a specification that defines the policies & rules that allow GraphQL clients and servers to communicate in real-time. And to implement the feature, you can use real-time tools like **Socket.io**.

For more detail, you can take a look at: https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/subscriptions/

Comment: Is there any performance issues between them?

Answer (score 12):

Here's my comparison as I had the same situation.

**GraphQL Subscriptions** -  Give updates when the data changes. It can triggered when a mutation takes place in your GraphQL server.  This is great as it keeps your logic tightly coupled. However, in the use case of a "Chat" application. This isn't the best.

**Socket.IO** - Provides a 2 Way Event notification services.  Therefore, you can send event from the clients without waiting on a GraphQL mutation to be executed.  For example: "User A is Typing..."  Or a User enters or leaves the conversation.

Comment: `It can triggered when a mutation takes place in your GraphQL server.`

actually you can trigger it whenever you want to by sending a message to the pubsub server.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the comparison is really on Apollo gql subscriptions vs socket.io. The benefit of the former is it is a boxed solution that tells you how to do everything, and the benefit of the latter is that you get to implement how to do everything.

I've used both at scale; under the hood they're basically the same technology and there aren't any performance differences. If you're using a gql server, then stick with that.